# Implementing noise cancellation function with PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, noise-reduction

In my PostgresSQL database, I have a table with columns `id` and an integer `value`.

The values contain noise that needs to be cleared out. I would like to do it by passing `n` (e.g. 5) consecutive values to the function and then calculate their median (or average or something similar). So given the records with values `4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 6, 4` the first output would be the median of the first 5 values (`4, 1, 3, 4, 4`), the second one would be the median of the first 5 values with offset one (`1, 3, 4, 4, 2`), then offset 2 and so forth.

I would like to use the function in a query like this `SELECT id, value, noisless_value(value) FROM measurements`. Is this doable with Postgres? Or should such computations be performed outside of the database?

Comment: So the output for your example records would be 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Postgres does not have a convenient way to calculating a running median using window functions. So, the following handles both the average and the median using a lateral join:

```
select t.*, t2.*
from t cross join lateral
     (select avg(value) as avg_5, percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by value) as median_5
      from (select t2.*
            from t t2
            where t2.id >= t.id
            order by t2.id asc
            limit 5
           ) t2
     ) t2;
```

The average, I should point out, is simpler using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       avg(value) over (order by id range between current row and 4 following) as avg_5
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1cf6dc5853cfebfbd9a2559a11383c37) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: A custom [median aggregate](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median) can be used as a window function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Do you have any sense why the `percentile_()` functions cannot be?  In many other databases, these are *only* window functions.

Comment: No idea. I guess as with many other missing things: nobody cared enough to implement it.